# How can i redirect a user with devise and cancan in rails 3 when the user comes back to the site and is still logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, authentication, devise

I am trying to find a way to redirect a user when they come back to the site if they are still logged in. I want them to be redirected to their specific home page. I am using rails 3, devise, and cancan.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If I leave your site and then come back I probably am coming back to a specific page, in that case I wouldn't want to be redirected. If you want logged-in users to see a custom home page ONLY in place of the normal home page, then just put that as a condition whatever controller you're using for your root path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise provides the method `user_signed_in?` that you could user to check if the user is already logged in.  Then you could use `current_user` to find the home page for the given user.

I would add something like this to the controller that user go through to get to your home page:

```
if user_signed_in?
  redirect_to current_user.home_page_path 
end
```

Note - This is assuming that your devise model is called User and you have added a method for home_page_path to the user model.

Comment: Good answer. As I commented above -- this code should go in whatever controller action you have assigned to :root.

Answer (score 0):

The [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) describes a few potential redirect solutions. You'll want to be careful using the `user_signed_in?` helper, as it will redirect any user that is signed in, rather than users that have *just* signed in.